# Emacs replace regexp with incremental sequence

Tags: regex, emacs, text-editor

I am trying to figure out a way to replace a string in a text file by a number that increments by more than 1. I am trying to turn a couple of lines like this:

```
result_A_in_S1-S2.txt
result_A_in_S1-S2.txt
result_A_in_S1-S2.txt
result_A_in_S1-S2.txt
```

Into something that scales up sequentially for `S1` and `S2`.

```
result_A_in_1000-1003.txt
result_A_in_1004-1007.txt
result_A_in_1008-1011.txt
result_A_in_1012-1015.txt
```

I want to know if I can define a string with replace regexp and then have that string be replaced with some starting number, and as it finds the next occurrence of string, it replaces with starting number + chosen increment.

I am just now starting learn Emacs and am pretty unfamiliar with it.

Comment: I'm guessing this might be a duplicate...

Comment: That was also my initial thought. I know there are other Q&As about generating sequences generally (which do tend to include answers like mine here, amongst other approaches), but this question had a specific need which seemed best met with a specific answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you *can* do that with [query-]replace-regexp in Emacs, by evaluating elisp in your replacement, and utilising the zero-based replacement counter `\#`. e.g.:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>
`query-regexp-replace`
<kbd>RET</kbd>
`S1-S2`
<kbd>RET</kbd>
`\,(let ((start (+ 1000 (* 4 \#)))) (format "%d-%d" start (+ start 3)))`
<kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so very much, I found a much dumber brute force work around, but it this is lovely. I have still so much to learn about emacs.