# regular expression replace text with order number

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a document with contains ## for list sign.
I want to replace ## with order numbers.

```
first matched ## -> to 1.
second matched ## -> 2.
.... 3.
.... 4.
```

Is this possible to do in an editor, like VS Code etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emacs replace regexp with incremental sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519627/emacs-replace-regexp-with-incremental-sequence)

Comment: @Biffen Emacs is a good editor. But it's not ease to use on windows or Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

The generate expression you want is: `{{=i+1}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without an extension by first selecting all the `##`'s you want to change.  One way is by a Find: `##` and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all those matches.

Then run this keybinding:

```
 {
  "key": "alt+w",   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "${CURSOR_NUMBER}"    // 1-based, CURSOR_INDEX is 0-based
  },
  "when": "editorHasSelection"
},
```

---

To combine the find, select all and replace in one step you can use  the extension [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform), which I wrote.  Here is a sample keybinding that will do what you want (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
 {
  "key": "alt+c",            // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "description": "increment hashes",
    "find": "##",
    "replace": "${matchNumber}",   
    "postCommands": "cancelSelection"
  }
 }
```

`${matchNumber}` is 1-based, `${matchIndex}` is 0-based.

[image: increment hashes demo]